# Networked A-frame object

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, aframe-networked

I am creating a scene in A-frame (https://aframe.io) using the networked A-frame component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/networked-aframe) and I'm wondering how I can create a "networked object" where when two users are in one scene and one user moves the object, it will update for both players and the object will move even for the player that hasnt moved anything. I want to use vr hands inside A-frame to move objects around my scene however currently when I move and object, the object only moves for one player and for the other player it remains in the same spot. Link to a networked a-frame boilerplate glitch project:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/networked-aframe?path=README.md%3A1%3A0

Code for a movable box I want in my scene that should update for both players:

```
<a-box hoverable grabbable stretchable draggable dropppable color="blue" position="0 0 -1"></a-box>
```